# Tornado server caused Django unable to handle concurrent requests

Tags: python, django, web, concurrency, tornado

I wrote a Django website that handles concurrent database requests and subprocess calls perfectly fine, if I just run "python manage.py runserver"

This is my model

```
class MyModel:
    ...
    def foo(self):
        args = [......]
        pipe = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subproccess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

In my view:

```
def call_foo(request):
    my_model = MyModel()
    my_model.foo()
```

However, after I wrap it using Tornado server, it's no longer able to handle concurrent request. When I click my website where it sends async get request to this call_foo() function, it seems like my app is not able to handle other requests. For example, if I open the home page url, it keeps waiting and won't display until the above subprocess call in foo() has finished.

If I do not use Tornado, everything works fine.

Below is my code to start the tornado server. Is there anything that I did wrong?

```
MAX_WAIT_SECONDS_BEFORE_SHUTDOWN = 5

def sig_handler(sig, frame):
    logging.warning('Caught signal: %s', sig)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(force_shutdown)

def force_shutdown():
    logging.info("Stopping tornado server")
    server.stop()
    logging.info('Will shutdown in %s seconds ...', MAX_WAIT_SECONDS_BEFORE_SHUTDOWN)
    io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    deadline = time.time() + MAX_WAIT_SECONDS_BEFORE_SHUTDOWN

    def stop_loop():
        now = time.time()
        if now < deadline and (io_loop._callbacks or io_loop._timeouts):
            io_loop.add_timeout(now + 1, stop_loop)
        else:
            io_loop.stop()
            logging.info('Force Shutdown')
    stop_loop()

def main():
    parse_command_line()
    logging.info("starting tornado web server")
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mydjango.settings'
    django.setup()
    wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())
    tornado_app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/(favicon\.ico)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': "static"}),
        (r'/static/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': "static"}),
        ('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),
      ])
    global server
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
    server.listen(options.port)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sig_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_handler)

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

    logging.info("Exit...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

There  is nothing wrong with your set-up. This is by design.

So, *WSGI* protocol (and so *Django*) uses **syncronous** model. It means that when your app starts processing a request it takes control and gives it back only when request is finished. That's why it can process single request at once. To allow simultaneous requests one usually launches *wsgi* application in multithreaded or multiprocessed mode.

The *Tornado* server on other side uses **asynchronous** model. The idea here is to have own scheduler instead of OS scheduler that works with threads and processes. So your code runs some logic, then launches some long task (DB call, URL fetch), sets up what to run when task finishes and gives control back to scheduler.

Giving controll back to scheduler is crucial part, it allows async server to work fast because it can start processing new request while previous is waiting for data.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079717/synchronous-v-s-asynchronous) explains sync/async detailed. It focuses on client, but I think you can see the idea.

So whats wrong with your code: `Popen` does not give control to `IOLoop`. Python does nothing until your subprocess is finished, and so can not process other requests, even not Django's requests. `runserver` "works" here because it's multithreaded. So while locking entirely the thread, other threads can still process requests.

For this reason it's usually **not recommended** to run *WSGI* apps under *async* server like tornado. The doc claims it will be *less scalable*, but you can see the problem on your own code. So if you need both servers (e.g. Tornado for sockets and Django for main site), I'd suggest to run both behind *nginx*, and use *uwsgi* or *gunicorn* to run *Django*. Or take a look at `django-channels` app instead of *tornado*.

Besides, while it works on test environment, I guess it's not a recomended way to do what you try to achieve. It's hard to suggest the solution, as I don't know what do you call with `Popen`, but it seams to be something long running. Maybe you should take a look at [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) project. It's a package for running long-term background job.

However, back to running sub-processes. In *Tornado* you can use [`tornado.process.Subprocess`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/process.html#tornado.process.Subprocess). It's a wrapper over `Popen` to allow it to work with `IOLoop`. Unfortunately I don't know if you can use it in *wsgi* part under *tornado*. There are some projects I remember, like [django futures](https://github.com/jeffbuttars/django-futures) but it seems to be abandoned.

As another quick and dirty fix - you can run *Tornado* with several processes. Check [`this example`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html#processes-and-ports) on how to fork server. But I will not recoment using this in production anyway (fork is OK, running wsgi fallback is not).

So to summarize, I would rewrite your code to do one of the following:

1. Run the Popen call in some background queue, like Celery
2. Process such views with Tornado and use `tornado.processes` module to run subprocess.

And overall, I'd seek for another deployment infrastructure, and would not run Durango under tornado.

Comment: Thank you @lgor! The explanation is very clear. Do you have any suggestions about what server I can use that would work well with Django for my purpose? The reason I need popen is that I have some legacy stuff that I have to call subprocess to run.

Comment: I would use https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to run Django app, perhaps behind Nginx. You can either run some amount of workers (threads x processes) and hope that such Popen-blocks are OK (they're OK, but it will handle small load, bigger amount of users can make server stuck). If you need higher load - check Celery. You will run a task, get task-id immediately, and you can return ID to client (browser). Browser will poll when task is ready and can load task results. But you will need to update both django view and template (some ajax polling)