# How can I write asynchronous codes with Tornado framework?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I read [tornado documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) but i don't understand it.
 I just know that asynchronous codes in tornado works with co_routines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you familiarize yourself with asynchronous vs synchronous calls and/or execution so as to have a general and firm understanding before proceeding.

This is a good starting point...[Synchronous v/s Asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079717/synchronous-v-s-asynchronous)

Comment: Thank you my friend